# How to create a helm source from a list of points?

Tags: helm, helm-sources

I have a list of lines in my current buffer, and I'd like to create a helm menu
for the user to select which point to navigate to. Ideally, I'd like a helm
source like helm-swoop's, but all the lines are load from my list of line
numbers rather than the entire buffer.